# Monster group as automorphism group of a distributive lattice

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattice-theory, monster

It is known that every finite group is the automorphism group of a finite distributive lattice.

> Question: What is the minimal order of a distributive lattice $L$ such that the automorphism group of $L$ is isomorphic to the monster group?

Are there particular nice distributive lattices (with any order) realising the monster group in that way?

Comment: By Birkoff's FTFDL, realizing a group as an automorphism group of a finite distributive distributive lattice is the same as realizing it as an automorphism group of a finite poset, right?

Comment: Anyways here is a reference to the result about automorphism groups of posets: https://people.kth.se/~jbarmak/automorphismgroups.pdf. I think in principle it gives you an algorithm to construct the poset in question.

Comment: You may take the union of the set of the 2A involutions in the Monster (in the sense of the ATLAS) and the set of triples of 2A involutions such that their product is the neutral element. Here the order is given by inclusion. Does this qualify as a 'nice' poset on which the Monster acts as the automorphism group?